# How to cleanup entries in OpenWith List?

Tags: wine

I was playing around with Wine and I have installed and uninstalled Windows software many times. When I open "Open With Application" I get many entries of a same application, is there any way to cleanup this list?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove ~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache

```
rm ~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

Restart Nautilus…

```
nautilus -q
```

[Credit for solution](http://marshallim.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/clean-up-wine-open-with-context-menu-items-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: sanjay@sanjay-ubuntu:~$ rm ~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
rm: cannot remove `/home/sanjay/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache': No such file or directory
sanjay@sanjay-ubuntu:~$

Comment: I don't have wine installed on this computer, Let me install it and See if I can help narrow it down further.

Comment: If you take one of the files in question, and right click on the executable. Select Properties and go to the open with tab. Can you highlight one of the many duplicates, then right click and select remove association?

Comment: many duplicates wont get highlighted, only one gets highlighted

Comment: I was hoping that would have worked out for you. I don't have the other applications that you've installed through wine, and I can't recreate the error. I will keep trying to see if I can duplicate it or hear of someone that has solved it, and modify this further.